# Razor helper file is not working from the WebDAV URL

Tags: tridion, razor-mediator

I am using some common function in Razor-Mediator templating,

As per the Razor doc, we can create a helper file and can define all the common function there.

```
<razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true" adminUser="XXX\pgupta">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Linq" />
      <add namespace="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Templating" />
    </namespaces>
    <assemblies>
      <!-- <add assembly="C:\Program Files\Assembly\Test.Sample.dll" /> -->
      <!--<add assembly="RazorSample.Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60ad7434f03dfcdc" />-->
    </assemblies>
    <imports>
      <!--<add import="tcm:4-21631-2048" />-->
      <add import="/webdav/04 Vanilla Layout/Building Blocks/System/Template Building Blocks/Razor/razor.cshtml" />
      <add import="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Razor Mediator\helper.cshtml" />
      <!-- <add import="tcm:120-2200-2048" publications="020 Design Master,030 Another Web Design" />-->
    </imports>
    <importSettings includeConfigWhereUsed="true" includeImportWhereUsed="true" replaceRelativePaths="false" />
  </razor.mediator>
```

i am successfully import these all function when I defined the physical path in the config file.

But, its not working when I defined the wevDAV URL in the config file,

Could any one please help me on this?

Comment: Could it be the miss spell of the name 'wevdav'

Comment: Sorry John, actually that was correct in my config file,

Comment: The escaped quote \" on the xml, seems a bit peculiar... just a thought

Comment: maybe the space in the file path too, you should probably url encode this value?  e.g the space ' ' should be %20

Comment: John: I have double check all cases and also using %20 in the path

Comment: Puntero: I have also checked both like way, suppose if i use this (\) then its find the file like physical path, and error me c:/.....

Comment: what's the actual error message you receive?  might be useful to let us know what you receive and what you've tried.  For example, does it work with the tcmid, does it work when trying to load files without the .cshtml extension?

Comment: It’s a Simple one,
I have created on function Social() in the razor TBB, and that TBB webDAV URL is passing in the config file.  When I use this function in other TBB then its display the error message  “The name 'Social' does not exist in the current context Line 261 Column 7: WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n\r\nHi\n\n"); * Write(Social()); } } } Stack Trace: at”
I have also tried to pass the TCMID in the config file, but it’s display the same error message

Comment: Did you enter a valid username in the 'adminUser' attribute?

Comment: @Priyank - As mentioned by others above, I would suggest that this is either: (1) The strange escaping of quotation marks  (2) The 'adminUser' is correct and has suitable permissions (3) The hyphen in the helper filename may be causing problems.  I have just checked my working Razor implementation and have the following: <add import="/webdav/200 Global Design/Building Blocks/System/Template Building Blocks/Custom/Razor/Component Templates/System/Razor_Template_Functions.cshtml"/>

Comment: @Jonathan-I have copied my updated code and covered your 1 & 3 points but still it is not working. Could you please explain more about 2nd point. I am an "adminuser" and which permission i have to set?

Comment: You have to specify the username (your username if you are an Administrator) in the 'adminUser' attribute of the <razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true"> tag. So: <razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true" adminUser="COMPANYDOMAIN\Priyank">

Comment: @Jonathan- I have added adminuser entry in the config file, but still getting the same error 
TemplateCompileException: CS0103: The name 'Social' does not exist in the current context 
 Line 28 Column 7: public override void Execute() {
 WriteLiteral("\r\nHi\n\n");
 * Write(Social());}}}.....

Comment: Have you been restarting the Tridion Content Manager COM+ Package and the Tridion Content Manager Service Host Service after changes to the config file?

Comment: @Chris - Yes, After these changes in the config file, i have restarted the services and IIS server also.

Comment: @Priyank - Can you actually browse to the functions item using webdav?

Comment: @Jonathan- Yes, i am able to see function if i use "Open with WeDAV" option.

Comment: At what point is it failing?  Is it when you try to publish or earier?   Are you definitely using version 1.2 (or later) of the Razor Mediator?  If it helps, here is my complete WebDav configuration that definitely works:<razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true" adminUser="DOMAIN\AdministratorUser">
<namespaces />
<assemblies />
<imports>     
<add import="/webdav/200 Global Design/Building Blocks/System/Template Building Blocks/Custom/Razor/Component Templates/System/Razor_Template_Functions.cshtml"/>      
</imports>
</razor.mediator>

Comment: @Jonathan-I have created a one function Social() in the razor TBB. When I use this function in other TBB and saved this then its display the error message “The name 'Social' does not exist in the current context Line 261 Column 7: WriteLiteral("\r\n\r\n\r\nHi\n\n"); * Write(Social()); } } } Stack Trace: at”. But when i use this function in the External file and added assembly "Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.TemplatingTridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Templating" then its work fine.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that if it was working okay with the tcmId or file location that you had the adminUser correct.  I guess that you are using v1.3 of the Razor Mediator if you have the <importSettings> elements.  Can you paste EXACTLY what is in your <imports> element please?  Thanks,Jonathan

Comment: @Jonathan- Yes, i am using V1.3 of the Razor Mediator. I have copied/updated the exactly code in my question. let me know if you need any other details

Comment: Hi Priyank.  Your configuration looks correct and assuming that the administrator user is configured correctly then I would suggest following the suggestion by @roberc below and downloading the latest version of the code from source.

Comment: @Priyank - have you solved this issue?

Comment: @ChrisSummers- No, My issue is not resolved. Today, i am going to setup a new environment and have installed razor.. 1.3 version.  Just for your update, i have also tried option to pass the tcmid of the razor helper file in the config setting, but still facing facing same issue. Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

I see spaces in your webdav path - is it like this or do you have %20 and SO is stripping them out?

I usually write a small VBScript Page Template and put use this code to get the webdav URL:

```
[%
dim uri, item
uri = "tcm:0-0-0"  ' update this uri and use the item in the parent repository
set item = TDSE.GeTObject(uri, 1)
WriteOut item.info.WebdavUrl
%]
```

Otherwise, the Razor 1.3 Mediator added Where Used functionality compatibility and this could be causing some issues.  The source code was updated to 1.31 but a compiled version of it is not on the Google Code Downloads.  You can grab the source and compile yourself to use the latest version:  http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/list